# Which option is selected in jQuery 1.2?

Tags: jquery, select

Finding out the current value of a select-list with jQuery 1.4 is easy:

```
$('#selectList').val();
```

But whats about jQuery 1.2?
I get an "undefinied".

I also tried

```
$('#selectList:selected').val();
$('#selectList option').val();
$('#selectList option:selected').val();
```

Nothing works but for this project i have to use jQuery 1.2

---

Sorry .val() works in jQuery 1.2, too.
my mistake

Comment: Why are you using jQuery 1.2? Try `$(...).attr('value')`.

Comment: I know it's a condition and I don't know the circumstances, but there are a *lot* of new things added in 1.3/1.4, try if at all possible upgrade for performance benefits and bug fixes.  If that's not possible, at least be on the latest 1.2, 1.2.6.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why `val()` isn't working for you, but you can get the element and use the plain DOM property, `value`:

```
$('#selectList')[0].value;

// or
$('#selectList').get(0).value;
```

Comment: `:selected` = 1.0 :) http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/ Also, `<select>` doesn't have a `value` property, more sleep Andy!

Comment: @Nick: yeah, I double checked `:selected` after I wrote it and removed that part.  1.3 was when they rewrote the selector engine (and created Sizzle) which is why I thought that.  However, `<select>` does have a *value* property - paste this into any current browser's console: `"value" in document.createElement("select")` :-)

Comment: @Andy - Hmm that *shouldn't* work, it's definitely not standard but maybe IE6 is the only reason I've never seen it used. +1 for an educational experience :) ...I never thought to try it since it's not in the HTML4 spec, kudos sir

Comment: @Nick: it works in IE6 too, and it's defined in [DOM level 1 under HTMLSelectElement](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-DOM-Level-1-20000929/level-one-html.html#ID-94282980) :-)

Comment: +1 - Although there is an IE6 issue where if you don't have the `value` attribute of the `<option>` elements set, it will not use the text content of the `<option>` in its place like other browsers do.

Comment: @patrick: yes, that is one potential issue I had overlooked and one you've pointed out to me before, I think.  I'll try to remember it in future :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this using [`:selected`](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) and [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
$('#selectList :selected').attr('value');
```

Though, [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) **should** be working (since jQuery 1.0), is there possibly a plugin breaking it? (Or, is Prototype in the page?)

The above is just approaching it differently, it gets the selected `<option>` and gets its `value=""` attribute directly, if that doesn't work, something is very wrong.